# Nil when calling a method on the variable, but not nil when calling just the variable

Tags: ruby

Don't understand why @nums.pop won't work in the value method. It seems to tell me that it can't do that for nil, but if I just say @nums, it shows that there is indeed something in the array. So then why can't I pop it out?

```
class RPNCalculator


    def initialize
        @value = value
        nums ||= []
        @nums = nums
    end


    def push(num)
        @nums << num
    end

    def plus
        if @nums[-2] == nil || @nums[-1] == nil
            raise "calculator is empty"
        else
            @value = @nums.pop + @nums.pop
            @nums.push(@value)
        end

    end

    def minus
        if @nums[-2] == nil || @nums[-1] == nil
            raise "calculator is empty"
        else
        @value = @nums[-2] - @nums[-1]
        @nums.pop(2)
        @nums.push(@value)
        end
    end

    def divide
        if @nums[-2] == nil || @nums[-1] == nil
            raise "calculator is empty"
        else
        @value = @nums[-2].to_f / @nums[-1].to_f
        @nums.pop(2)
        @nums.push(@value)
        end
    end

    def times
        if @nums[-2] == nil || @nums[-1] == nil
            raise "calculator is empty"
        else
        @value = @nums.pop.to_f * @nums.pop.to_f
        @nums.push(@value)
        end
    end

    def value
        @nums #Don't understand why @nums.pop won't work here
    end

    def tokens(str)
        str.split(" ").map { |char| (char.match(/\d/) ? char.to_i : char.to_sym)}
    end

    def evaluate(str)

        tokens(str).each do |x| 

            if x == ":-"
                minus

            elsif x == ":+"
                plus

            elsif x == ":/"
                divide

            elsif x ==":*"
                times

            else
                push(x) 
            end
        end
        value
    end 
end
```

Error relates to the following part of a spec:

```
it "adds two numbers" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.plus
    calculator.value.should == 5
end
```

Error says either:

```
Failure/Error: calculator.value.should == 5
expected: 5
got: [5] <using ==>
```

OR if .pop is used

```
Failure/Error: @calculator = RPNCalculator.new
NoMethodError:
undefined method 'pop' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Remember that in Ruby the only two logically false values are `nil` and `false`. This makes direct comparisons to `nil` using `== nil` or `.nil?` almost always redundant. `unless @nums[-2] && @nums[-1]` is preferable to what you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialize method assigning `@value = value` calls the function at `def value` which returns `@nums` which has **not yet been created** in initialize since @nums is created afterwards with `nums ||= []; @nums = nums` therefore it's **nil**.  This is why .pop won't work.

You've created @nums as an array with `nums ||= []` and you're using it with push and pop so why are you checking for the value with value.should == 5 (Integer) when calling `value` returns an (Array).  You would need to write it like value.first.should == 5 or value[0].should == 5 ... otherwise you should change value to return just the element you want

```
def value
  @nums.pop # or @nums[0], or @nums.first or @nums.last however you plan on using it
end
```

The problem is **@value = value** in your initialize method.  Fix that then you can add the .pop in value.

**EDIT**

Also your evaluation is calling methods before you've populated @nums with the values.  Then the methods "raise" errors.  You can't call minus after only one value has been pushed to @nums.

Here's how I would do the flow for splitting the string

```
# Multiplication and Division need to happen before addition and subtraction
mylist = "1+3*7".split(/([+|-])/)
=> ["1", "+", "3*7"] 

# Compute multiplication and division
mylist = mylist.map {|x| !!(x =~ /[*|\/]/) ? eval(x) : x }
=> ["1", "+", 21]

# Do the rest of the addition
eval mylist.join
=> 22
```

I realize this isn't exactly how you're going about solving this... but I think splitting by order of mathematical sequence will be the right way to go.  So first evaluate everything between (), then only multiplication and division, then all addition and subtraction.

**EDIT** I just looked into what a RPN Calculator is.  So don't mind my splitting recommendation as it doesn't apply.

Comment: Since I don't want the program to call the value method at initialize, I thought that I should change the variable "value" to "sum". However, that is now causing another ripple effect that I am not understanding either. Should I re-paste the code showing that? Because now I am getting an error in a different part of the spec (error: calculator is empty):                                  it "adds three numbers" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.push(4)
    calculator.plus
    calculator.value.should == 7
    calculator.plus
    calculator.value.should == 9
  end

Comment: Try setting value to either nil or 0 instead.  So `@value = 0`.  That way you're not calling the value method.

Comment: That also leads me to the error of "calculator is empty" for when it adds three numbers

Comment: 2.1.2 :101 > x.push 2
 => [2] 
2.1.2 :102 > x.push 3
 => [2, 3] 
2.1.2 :103 > x.push 4
 => [2, 3, 4] 
2.1.2 :108 > x.plus
 => [2, 7] 
2.1.2 :109 > x.plus
 => [9]
Your plus feature works.  Do you have to do it this way?  Because there are much easier ways within Ruby to do this.

Comment: If I were you I'd change your methods to use inject.  For example `@nums.inject(:+)` or `@nums.inject(:*)` or `@nums.inject(:-)` or `@nums.inject(:/)` ... that will do the math on all the items within the array.

Comment: You were right, plus feature is working. The other error was because I was popping the value out, instead of accessing it, so the original sum couldn't be added upon. I will have to try the inject method to see how that might clean it up. However, before I change everything, could you help me understand one more thing? If I change to '@value = 0', and change to '@nums[-1]' (under def value). Everything works until the spec:     it "evaluates a string" do
        calculator.evaluate("1 2 3 * +").should ==
      ((2 * 3) + 1). It returns ":+", which I didn't think was being pushed into @nums

Comment: Your evaluation is checking for the string version of sym's where your tokenizer is returning the actual syms  So :- and not ":-" ... Array can contain symbols... so the array is coming back like [3, :-, 4] and not [3, ":-", 4]